# How to read reminders in google calendars

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar, reminders

I'm trying to read the reminders set by the user. What I mean with "reminder": currently there are two different meaning, the first one is the "alert" related to each event in the calendar and you can read them from `CalendarContract.Reminders`, the second one are unrelated events inserted by the user via Google Now with "remember me to...." or via Google Calendar app with insert reminder action. I'm talking about the second one.
I'm reading from the event table `CalendarContract.Events`. However it seems that this information is not saved there or it's not accessible. Is there a different content provider for reminders?

Comment: That reminder functionality is not available as far as I know.

Comment: @luc Yep, I didn't find any documentation. It seems that there isn't any public API

Comment: @greywolf82 Any updates on this one? Thanks.

Comment: @OferR is there is any updates on this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Reminders data seems to be held in a database accessible by the 'com.google.android.gms.reminders.provider.RemindersProvider' content provider.

Unfortunately, the provider is not exported and therefore is not accessible to third party apps.

Needless to say that the content provider is not documented and no public API exists.

Comment: Any updates on this? Maybe we should create an issue on google's tracker. Where this tracker for Google calendar?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use  ['ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER'](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html#ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER) broadcast, this intent get fired when an alarm notification needs to be posted for a reminder (android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER).

Here's a sample code for EVENT_REMINDER:

```
<receiver android:name="com.eshayne.android.CalendarTest">
<intent-filter>
<data android:scheme="content"/> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>


IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(CalendarContract.ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER);
filter.addDataScheme("content"); 
registerReceiver(myRemindersReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question