# How to get reminders list programmatically?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I created an Android app that read all the events of the calendar, it's work fine but I can't read the list of reminders: the simplified event in the Google calendar identified by this icon (knot on the finger)

[Google Calendar Reminder](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285327?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid)

Someone can tell me how can I read this type of event or where can I find a tutorial or a guide where this is explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the reminders aren't only on calendar but are in different Google app (keep for example). 
Unfortunately it's not possible to access a this kind of data.

This the link of the answer in Stackoverflow: [How to read reminders in google calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534774/how-to-read-reminders-in-google-calendars/37035037#37035037)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch list of reminders, use [Events.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list). It returns events and the accompanying reminders.

[Default reminders](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders)

> Default reminders are also returned when 
>    doing an Events list query.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I need to read the reminders from Google Calendar not the events with the reminders settings inside.
The reminders I can't read are the simplified events provided by the google calendar

Answer (score 0):

According to [OferR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534774/how-to-read-reminders-in-google-calendars/37035037#37035037) The Reminders data is held in a database and accessible by the 'com.google.android.gms.reminders.provider.RemindersProvider' content provider.

So, the provider is not exported and therefore is not accessible to third party apps.